# How am I supposed to interpret the negative and positive intervals in this graph?

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

The Graph:

[image]

I'm tripped up over paragraph two. I don't think it's right. I think the graph is negative at $-10 < x < -9$ and $-2 < x < 4$ and positive at $-9 < x < -2$ and $4 < x < 10$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's printing mistake I think @JimGordon

Comment: @gimusi  If you plan to enlarge the graph, please also write out in text the second paragraph that the OP explicitly refers to.  Your last edit removed the text that is part of why this asker asked the question.

Comment: @amWhy Yes sorry I agree, I didn't noticed at first the importance of the text and I enlarged that to make it more clear. But in that way it is better of course.

Comment: "To the right of 4, the graph is below the x-axis, meaning that it is negative." Hmmm... are you sure about that textbook?

Comment: @JimGordon Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only you're absolutely right, but it is a pretty poor phrasing altogether to say that *a graph is negative*. A number can be negative, not a graph. It is important to understand that maths is made of objects of different nature (that can be *related* in a number of ways) and to use precise and appropriate terminology so as not to mix up these objects.

I wouldn't recommend this book to any of my classes, at any level.

Comment: Yea it is The Princeton Review "Cracking the GED test". I've come across completely wrong explanations a couple times in this book. It really throws me off.

Comment: @JimGordon Thanks for the precision. Sometimes editors do pay attention to feedback, so it might be worthwhile sending them an email - although you'd be doing their job.

Comment: Although I rather wouldn't use the phrase myself, I don't see much objectable about saying “the graph is negative” for “the function has negative values”. What's your concern?

Comment: @leftaroundabout It encourages all kinds of mix up. If you are mathematically grown up, you are going to be able to stick to relatively reasonable misuse of language. But students tend to mix up *everything* and end up with totally nonsensical statements where you can only sometimes even *guess* what they meant. You need to teach them to use proper language systematically and from the beginning if you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is correct, we can say that

- $f$ is negative for $-10<x<-9$ and $-2<x<4$
- $f$ is positive for $-9<x<-2$ and $4<x<10$

since we don't have information for values $x<-10$ and $x>10$.